# how tocreate a full pbr concrete material

Tags: modeling, materials, shaders, procedural, pbr

I need to reproduce the concrete wall in the image, with procedural method:
[image]

in particular:

1. a procedure for create random small holes effect
2. these irregular straight lines in relief
3. some wet spots effects above the base texture

Comment: have you tried to create the material yourself? where are you having trouble? please [add images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/190637/edit) that show your current material and setup so that other users can better help you. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try for procedural concrete, basically it's only *Noise Texture* nodes mixed together (with *Math/Add* nodes or with *MixRGB/Overlay* nodes) to have various sizes and shapes of 3D bumps and grey spots:

[image]
[image]

File: [image]