# How do I create such material?+un-wraping

Tags: materials, uv, shader-nodes

Sorry for such a basic question, but how do I recreate such material? I tried making this kind of concrete material in substance designer and browsed the whole internet for the right textures, but it still seems like a long way from my goal. 
I want it to look as photorealistic as possible.
How should I do it?

I also have problems when it comes to un-wraping the model (smart UV doesn't seem to work and can't figure out where to put those seams on the model)

I'd appreciate a little help with that too. (I'll include the project file).

Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]

[image]

---

UPD: There is a texture I created in SD, but still looking for your suggestions to make it better. Also would appreciate some suiting image textures. (But like I said, I searched the whole internet through and didn't find anything perfect for my purposes)
[image]

Comment: Hi. I think you forgot to pack your materials before you uploaded the file (_File > External Data _ Pack Resources_).

Comment: Also, I notice your object has non-uniform scale (comes from scaling in object mode). Select your mesh in object mode and press Ctrl+A (apply) and select "Scale".

Comment: Thanks for the scale suggestion. I definitely overlooked that.

Comment: But also I didn't want to include textures since they, don't really resemble the texture I was going after.

Answer (score 1):

You could mix a big *Noise Texture* for the background spots with a smaller *Noise Texture* for the small dots, use a *Color > MixRGB* in *Multiply* mode in order to mix. You can create a texture before the *Mapping* of the big *Noise Texture* in order to twist it a bit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It looks nice, but it is far from what I am looking for. Like I said, I really need a photorealistic look for a close-up.

Comment: it just needs additional layers of textures. But if you want realism, why not use real picture of concrete?

Comment: here is another try: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190637/how-tocreate-a-full-pbr-concrete-material

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it